# Report generation based on multi lookup and dynamic columns

Tags: excel, reporting-services, report, reporting, ssrs-tablix

I am a little stuck with  a report I am trying to generate in `Excel` and was hoping someone could help.
Here is a summary of what I am trying to do:

- Table 1 has one column called people (it’s basically a list of
  employees)
- Table 2 has one column called countries (it’s basically a
  list of relevant countries)
- Table 3 has three columns called person,
  country and date.

There is one entry for every person each time they review a country.

So the data will look something like:

```
PERSON      |  COUNTRY         |    DATE
John        |   uk             |    10/01/2013
Paul        |   uk             |    15/01/2013
John        |   France         |    15/01/2013
Bob         |   Spain          |    16/01/2013
```

The report I need to produce is one which shows who has/hasn't checked each country.
So the columns will be ‘Person’, uk, France, Spain (and any other unique value from the country table).

There will then be one single row for each person with a Yes/No value in the relevant column if that person has reviewed that country i.e. Table 3 contains a value that matches that value for the person and country.

So to be clear the report should be similar to:

```
PERSON      |  UK       |  FRANCE   |  SPAIN   
John        |   Yes     |   Yes     |   No
Paul        |   Yes     |   No      |   No
Bob         |   No      |   No      |   Yes
```

In summary I can split this into two problems:

1. How to generate a table that has a column for every unique value in another table (country in the explanation above)
2. How to do a double lookup i.e. `IF EXISTS in TABLE 3 ‘person’=john & ‘country’=uk` then return ‘Yes’, otherwise return ‘No’

I’m happy to keep in `Excel` or make use of `SQL` reporting i.e move my data to `SQL` first.

Answer (score 0):

It's kind of a wonky formula but `=sumproduct()` will do a dual lookup.

`=IF(SUMPRODUCT(--($K$2:$K$5=$K13), --($L$2:$L$5=M$10)),"Yes","No")`

The Person/Country/Date table is located in the range `K1:M5` the results table is located in range `K10:N13`. I had a workbook open and put it in the corner. (Nobody puts sumproduct in the corner)

The gist is, `--` turns a true and false into a 1 or 0. sumproduct will multiply the two results line by line. If both are true, you get 1 x 1 and funnels that back into the if for a yes and no. You'll have to be mindful of th `$` in the formula.